# What is explpreset actually for?

Tags: showexpl

`showexpl` package is intended to show (La)TeX, TikZ, PSTricks codes and their coressponding rendered outputs at the same time (either horizontally or vertically).

> Note that it cannot be used to show C# or C++ or Mathematica or others and their outputs because these language use different compilers or render engines.

`showexpl` is derived from `listings` package so options defined in `listings` can be used in `showexpl` either by using `\lstset{...}` or `\lstset{explpreset={...}}` as follows.

```
\lstset
{
    backgroundcolor=\color{pink}
}
```

or

```
\lstset
{
   explpreset=% I add the missing = here!
   {
     backgroundcolor=\color{pink}
   }
}
```

I have read the `showexpl` package and the source code of its example document, but I am still confused what `explpreset` is actually for--because `\lstset{}` already exists and it can do what `explpreset` wants to do. The following is a short description of `explpreset`:

[image]

Do you have idea, what is `explpreset` is actually for?

Comment: Thanks for those who answered this question. All of them have been given a plus one for their good answers. However I have only one green check mark and it was given to Martin for the technical details. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `explpreset` key simply stores its value into the `\SX@explpreset` macro which is later used inside a local `\lstset`. This allows to define `listings` settings only for `showexpl` listings but not for other ones.

The exact usage is as follows:

`showexpl.dtx`, 2007/02/03 v0.3h, line 251:

```
\lst@Key{explpreset}\relax{\def\SX@explpreset{#1}}
```

by default it is empty: (line 285)

```
\newcommand*\SX@explpreset{}
```

It is then used by the `LTXexample` environment to set local `\lstset` settings: (starting from line 423)

```
\lstnewenvironment{LTXexample}[1][]
{%
  \@temptokena{#1}%
  \begingroup
%    \end{macrocode}
% For "codefile=..."/"graphic=..." if \cmd{\theltxexample} or 
% \cmd{\thelstlisting} is part of the filename.
%    \begin{macrocode}
    \advance\c@ltxexample\@ne \advance\c@lstlisting\@ne 
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset,#1}%
```

This environment writes the code into an external file and calls the `\SX@put@code@result` macro afterwards to typeset it. This macro again uses the same settings: (line 457-)

```
\newcommand*\SX@put@code@result{%
  \begingroup
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset}%
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the `explpreset` key inside `lstset`, you can customize only the attributes for the `LTXexampe` environments, and this gives you the possibility to define different attributes for the `lstlisting` environment. A simple example illustrating this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstset{
  explpreset={backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}},
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\LaTeX
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{LTXexample}
\LaTeX
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]