# \lstset{numbers=none} not working

Tags: listings, showexpl

I'm trying to have LaTeX examples in a document. I use the `showexpl` package which lets me use the `listings` package options. Because all fragments are short, line numbers are redundant.

The following MWE does not yield the result I want (i.e. there is a line number).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{numbers=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
Hello World!
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

When I define the option local(`\begin{LTXexample}[numbers=none]`) the number is gone. I would rather delete them globally and not have to type extra code for every example, so using a new style would preferably be avoided.

I think the solution will be somewhat [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128713/lstinputlisting-does-not-respect-the-lstset-float-option).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{explpreset={numbers=none}}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
Hello World!
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

You can read about the `ęxplpreset` parameter [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25123/what-is-explpreset-actually-for).

Update: if you specify `explpreset={}` the result will be the same (because this is the default)